# How to give a unchangeable, fixed hostname a Raspberry Pi 3 like a fixed IP address?

Tags: wireless, wifi-direct

I'm using my Raspberry Pi 3 wirelessly. If I switch off power connection or reset my wifi router, the hostname changes. I've reserved a IP address from TP-LINK router that is `192.168.0.105` and it does not change.

But hostname keeps changing again and again.

Please could you help me to give it a fixed hostname so that it does not change after resetting or power off my Pi?

Comment: Right out of the box, Raspbian comes with the default hostname `raspberrypi`. The only potential way to overwrite this setting temporarily might be your DHCP server sending a different hostname and/or FQDN option, but I've never seen this with typical home routers. But as you don't supply any details as what is happening, not even the old and new hostname, it's more or less impossible to help. Did you install some bogous third party software that messes with the hostname?

Comment: Hostname? Your hostname should **never** change unless you or some software you're running does it for you. Do you mean IP address?

Answer (score 2):

Try 
`sudo raspi-config` 
and navigate to 
`advanced options`

Answer (score 1):

Have you set the host name with the `hostname` command on the Pi?

`man hostname`